This `dispatch()` is completely ignored. Why?
I created a reproduction for an issue with Svelte dispatch not being called:
Steps to reproduce

Open the reproduction

Open the browser console

Go on the "About" page using the link

I sould see the message: "handleInput" but I'm not


Relevant code
<script>
    import Select from 'svelte-select';
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';

    export let value = undefined;
    export let id = undefined;
    
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
    
    let result;

    let items = [
        { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
        { value: 'two', label: 'Two' },
        { value: 'three', label: 'Three' },
    ];

    $: if (id !== undefined) {
        result = id;
    }

    $: if (result != undefined) {
        value = { value: 'custom', label: 'Custom' };
        console.log("this should dispatch!")
        dispatch('input', value);
        console.log("is it dispatched?")
    }
</script>

<Select {value} {items} on:change on:input />

The dispatch('input', value) is completely ignored.
Why?

To be clear, the term "REPL" refers to things like the prompt in the browser console, where you can type statements and have them evaluated. It stands for "Read-Eval-Print Loop".  The linked stackblitz site is not a REPL.

if you wrap dispatch('input', value); in a setTimeout it seems to work - perhaps you're using dispatch too early (I'm not familiar with svelte component lifecycles to let you know the proper way to do it)

@JaromandaX thanks. I cannot use the setTimeout there because it creates an infinite loop!

erm, no it doesn't, because that's how I determined that given a timeout it works as expected, with no infinite loop - I mean, how could there be an infinite loop just because you dispatch an event "later"? edit: you probably wrapped more than I suggested in the setTimeout .... JUST the dispatch ... nothing more - please note, I am NOT suggesting this is a solution - as I already said, I'm not familiar with svelte component lifecycles to offer a proper solution to your requirements

at a guess, you'd want to dispatch inside onMount

in fact, if you move that code to onMount you probably won't need to "manually" dispatch!

Yeah. It works in this simple case but in my real app it doesnt because result is coming from another reactive store.

I can't help with svelte in general, and nobody can help with code you haven't shown - I'm amazed I, with no knowledge of svelte, helped with the code you did show

it is much complicated to reproduce the complete code!

indeed - but now you know about onMounted - you've learned something

I think this is the reason: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4470

Reproduction steps are:

Navigate to 'about' page
✅ Observe handleInput not being logged to browser console (this failed successfully)

Your reactive statements are firing before the on:input event listener attaches to the <Select> component. This may be due to the fact that reactive statements are called before the DOM (or component markup) mounts, and event listeners are attached after the component mounts.
The reason your setTimeout code works is because it adds a microtask that likely registers after the event listeners get set up; so when its callback function fires, your on:input listener will receive the dispatched event. Similarly, using await tick() makes your code work for the same reason:
async function dispatchEvent () {
  value = { value: 'custom', label: 'Custom' };
  console.log("this should dispatch!")

  // wait for all microtasks to complete before continuing
  await tick() 
  dispatch('input', value);
  console.log("is it dispatched?")
}

$: if (result != undefined) {
  dispatchEvent()
}

With that said, having many reactive statements is challenging to follow. I recommend refactoring to use event listeners in your CustomSelect.svelte, which can be combined with event forwarding:
<Select on:input={internalInputHandler} on:input on:change />
<!--    ^ handle input                  ^ forward input -->

I also recommend dispatching events with a custom name, rather than override native event names; that way you can handle them separately and expect the native InputEvent for on:input. You could name your dispatched event input--id:
<!-- Component.svelte -->
<script>
  function handler() {
    dispatch('input:component', { some: 'detail' })
  }
</script>

<!-- +page.svelte -->
<Select on:input--id={doSomething} on:input={doSomethingElse} />

